# Как правильно сделать такой эффекти при наведении

Tags: css

[image: Вот такой эффект.]

Я делал примерно  так:

```
.result_section div.hover_btn::after {
    content: '';
    width: 107%;
    width: calc(100% + 15px);
    top: -82px;
    height: 115%;
    background: linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 15px, black 0) top right, linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 15px, black 0) bottom left;
    border: 0;
    background-size: 6% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Но получается слишком большая тень.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.long-shadow {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background: #03f;
  color: #fff;
  
  /* длинную тень в css можно сделать так */
  box-shadow: 
    1px  1px  0 0 #999,
    2px  2px  0 0 #999,
    3px  3px  0 0 #999,
    4px  4px  0 0 #999,
    5px  5px  0 0 #999,
    6px  6px  0 0 #999,
    7px  7px  0 0 #999,
    8px  8px  0 0 #999,
    9px  9px  0 0 #999,
    10px 10px 0 0 #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="long-shadow">Эффект длинной тени</div>
```

**С эффектом при наведение**

```css
.long-shadow {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background: #03f;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.long-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 
    1px  1px  0 0 #999,
    2px  2px  0 0 #999,
    3px  3px  0 0 #999,
    4px  4px  0 0 #999,
    5px  5px  0 0 #999,
    6px  6px  0 0 #999,
    7px  7px  0 0 #999,
    8px  8px  0 0 #999,
    9px  9px  0 0 #999,
    10px 10px 0 0 #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="long-shadow">Эффект длинной тени</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я правильно понял, что чем больше у нас строк, тем длиннее тень  будет?

Comment: @dmitriy_vlz, да)

Comment: Как все просто оказывается)

Comment: добавишь трансформацию, эффект будет красивее

Answer (score 0):

```
.result_section::hover{
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Цифры подобрать по желанию